# Empty password field on an asp:login form using a LayoutTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an `asp:login` control on an `.aspx` page. I'm using a `LayoutTemplate`. When a user enters a wrong username or password, on `postback`, the password field appears to be filled. So if the user only changes the username and try to log in again, it returns an error. Debugging I've seen that the password is empty.

I've tested the same behavior using the default `asp:login`, without `LayoutTemplate`, and it works well. It means that after entering a wrong username or password, on `postback`, the password field appears empty.

How can I make it work?

EDIT:

This is the code I use. When something is wrong and postback occurs, password field appears filled. If the user clicks again to login, on debug mode, I see that the password is empty.

```
<asp:Login ID="lgLogin" runat="server"
FailureText="Wrong data"
TextLayout="TextOnLeft" 
OnAuthenticate="lgLogin_Authenticate" 
DestinationPageUrl="http://www.blablabla.com/"
OnLoginError="lgLogin_Error"
RenderOuterTable="false"
DisplayRememberMe="False">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lgLogin_UserName" class="col-md-4 control-label">Login <span class="require">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>                
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lgLogin_Password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password <span class="require">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="password" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="AvisoError" runat="server" class="alert alert-danger" visible="false">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
        <span>
            <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
            <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Entrar" />
        </div>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>           
<TextBoxStyle CssClass="form-control"/>
<LoginButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

If I use the default asp:login, if something goes wrong and postback occurs, password appears empty.

```
<asp:Login ID="lgLogin" runat="server"
FailureText="Wrong data"
TextLayout="TextOnLeft" 
OnAuthenticate="lgLogin_Authenticate" 
DestinationPageUrl="http://www.blablabla.com/"
RenderOuterTable="false"
DisplayRememberMe="False">
```

Comment: Could you please add the code? It will be easier to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have set the textbox or input id to password field and it will go off when a postback occurs. Good practices are to leave it as it is and let user enter it one more time because there is a reason why this functionality has been there, and even if you want to push it anyhow then.

Firstly set your autocomplete property for the form to off. Then at page_load, store the password textbox value to some temp variable and then push that temp variable value to textbox. For more security, you can store that password field value to session and then encrypt it with base64 and then use it.

Comment: I want to leave it as it is, and that's empty. But on the screen, it appears as it is filled. If I use the default login, on postback, the textbox appears empty, which is OK. But if I use a LayoutTemplate, the password textbox appears as it's filled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an  attribute at the  to retain the state of the controls after postback

Answer (score 0):

Change type of field on load page event completed, works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
        document.getElementById("textBoxSenha").type = "password";
    });
```